# How do i make this double union to a single union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $m:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a function.

Let $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of mutually disjoint sets.

Let $\{E_{n,0},...,E_{n,m_n}\}$ be a mutually disjoint finite sequence such that $A_n = \bigsqcup_{0≦i≦m_n} E_{n,i}$.

Let $D=\bigsqcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \bigsqcup_{0≦i≦m_n} E_{n,i}$.

I want to make this union as a single union. That is, how do i construct a sequence of sets $\{C_k\}$ each $C_k$ is one of $E_{n,i}$'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$f:I\rightarrow\cup\left\{ \left\{ \left(n,0\right),\ldots,\left(n,m_{n}\right)\right\} \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} =\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{ n\right\} \times\left\{ 0,\ldots,m_{n}\right\} $$
be a bijection and define: $C_{i}:=E_{f\left(i\right)}$ for $i\in I$.

Then: $D=\cup_{i\in I}C_{i}$

In fact 'nothing' happens. You can take $I=\cup\left\{ \left\{ \left(n,0\right),\ldots,\left(n,m_{n}\right)\right\} \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ and let $f$ be the identity.

Comment: Is i should be $\bigcup \{n\}\times \{0,...,m_n\}$?

Comment: Yes you are right. I will repair.